# Noether's theorem in field theory: Jacobian factor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, noethers-theorem, variational-calculus

Following my earlier question in this Phys.SE [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174615/) I have another question regarding the [derivation](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~aruty101/CFT.pdf) I am struggling through!

Considering the variation in the Lagrange density for $x'=x+\delta x$ and $\phi'(x')=\phi(x)+\delta \phi (x)$. 
 \begin{equation}
 \mathcal L'(x')=\mathcal L'(x) +\frac {d \mathcal L}{d x^i}\delta x^i=\mathcal L(x)+\underbrace{\mathcal L'(x)-\mathcal L (x)}_{\bar \delta \mathcal L(x)}+\frac {d \mathcal L}{d x^i}\delta x^i
\end{equation}
Such that the variation in the action is given by,
\begin{equation}
\delta S=\int [\mathcal L(x)+\bar \delta \mathcal L(x)+\frac {d \mathcal L}{d x^i}\delta x^i ]dx'-\int \mathcal L(x) dx
\end{equation}
How then do we obtain the following,
\begin{equation}
\delta S=\int \big[\bar \delta \mathcal L(x)+\frac{d }{d x^i}(\mathcal L\delta x^i)\big]dx
\end{equation}

I understand it is to do with the Jacobian of the transformation that we approximate $$dx'=dx(1+\partial _i\delta x^i+\dots ),$$ but how does this follow and what exactly does this mean (again sorry if its obvious).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how we taylor expand the determinant to first order
\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}&= \text{det}\left(\frac{\partial x'^j}{\partial x^i} \right) \\
&= \text{det}\left(\delta _i ^j + \partial_i\delta x^j\right) \\
&= \text{exp}\left( \text{tr log }\left(\delta _i ^j + \partial_i\delta x^j\right)\right) \\
&= \text{exp}\left( \text{tr }\partial_i\delta x^j + \mathcal{O}(\delta x^2)\right) \\
&=1 + \text{tr }\partial_i\delta x^j + \mathcal{O}(\delta x^2)\\
&=1 + \partial_i\delta x^i + \mathcal{O}(\delta x^2)
\end{align}